# Grant full access to JupyterLab after updating to macOS Catalina

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab, macos-catalina

After updating my MacBook to "Catalina", Anaconda was sent to the folder "Relocated Items" on Desktop. I followed the official guide [Restore Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) and everything seemed to work fine.

Although, I realised that I cannot navigate to directories such as Documents and Desktop via Jupyterlab, while I can via Jupyter. I have already given full disk access to Anaconda from Settings and I can access any non-default directory, such as OneDrive or IntelliJ.

There is no response every time I try to click on default directories and I do not get any particular error.

If there is not any obvious solution, what am I going to lose if I reinstall Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up anaconda and turned to homebrew to install jupyter.
I had this issue as well, running Catalina on my old MBP 2012.
I tried re-install anaconda (2019-10 version) but it failed to update jupyter lab and notebook.
I had many problems with anaconda's update function these days, and I had enough of it.
So, I tried installing jupyter with homebrew and it worked perfectly.
When I access Desktop or Documents, a system dialog asking for permission would pop up.
Grant it permission and everything worked fine.
You might wanna try other ways to install jupyter lab as well, such as pip and docker.

Comment: For posterity: This solved my issue trying to run remote Mac applications, such as chromedriver